# Quantized tflite model has large sized apk than unquantized

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Hi I have trained inceptionV3 classification model with custom dataset and got retrained.pb and retrained_labels.txt. I want to use the model in mobile phone and I converted the model using the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
graph_def_file = "retrained_graph.pb"
input_arrays = ["Mul"]
output_arrays = ["final_result"]
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
  graph_def_file,input_arrays,output_arrays)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

I got the tflite model which is of size 85 MB and built an apk file which comes with size 113 MB and I quantized the model with following command

```
tflite_convert \
  --output_file=foo.tflite \
  --graph_def_file=retrained_graph.pb \
  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --input_arrays=Mul \
  --output_arrays=final_result \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --std_dev_values=127 \
  --default_ranges_min=0 \
  --default_ranges_max=6
```

It gives me a tflite model of size 21 MB and when i use this quantized model to build an apk it generates an apk file of size 135 MB.

My questions are

1. Why the size of the apk file is increased when i use the quantized model ?
2. How to reduce the apk size built with tflite model ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to remove the original model from the APK. So you are actually building the quantized model AND the float model into the APK.